# How to use a StringVar from a different thread to display a value in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, variables, tkinter

I am writing a software that contains a GUI and a script that reads data from a CO2 sensor via UART.

I have both of them in a separate file and I import the sensor script into the gui script. I run the sensor script in a separate thread. In my GUI I want to display the current value read by the sensor. Therefore I try to access the variable `live_co2` from the sensor script in the GUI script.

The issue I have is that while the `live_co2` shows the correct value in the sensor script I only get `live_co2` = `0` in the GUI script. I am using a recursive function with the `after()` function from tkinter to refresh the value in the GUI script.

GUI script:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk #Graphische Benutzeroberflaeche
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory #wird benoetigt um ordner auszuwählen
from pathlib import Path #um Dateien in einem Ordner aus zu lesen
import threading
import serial
import time
import csv
import CO2 #the sensor script

ppm = 400
measuring = False
options = ["manual", "time", "number"]

measuring_thread = CO2.meas()
measuring_thread.start()

#function get dir
def get_dir():
    browse_text.set("Browsing...")
    directory = askdirectory()
    global dir_file
    dir_file.set(directory)
    browse_text.set("Browse")

#function start measurement
def start_measurement():
    global measuring
    global dir_file
    if measuring: # for ending the measurement
        mes_btn_txt.set("Start measurement")
        measuring = False
        CO2.meas.log = False
        print("Stopping measurement")
    else: # for the start of the measurement
        mes_btn_txt.set("Stop measurement")
        measuring = True
        file_name = entry.get()
        str_dir_file = dir_file.get()# macht daraus einen String
        index = 0
        check = True
        file_name_new = file_name
        while check:
            file_url = str_dir_file + "/" + file_name_new + ".csv"
            file_url_path = Path(file_url)
            if file_url_path.is_file():
                index += 1
                file_name_new = file_name + "(" + str(index) + ")"
            else:
                check = False
        print(file_url)
        CO2.meas.path = file_url
        CO2.meas.log = True

def input_loop():
    current_text.set(str(CO2.meas.live_co2))
    print(CO2.meas.live_co2)
    CO2.meas.type = option_chosen.get()
    if CO2.meas.type == "time":
        CO2.meas.t = limit_entry.get()
    elif CO2.meas.type == "number":
        CO2.meas.num = limit_entry.get()
    root.after(1000, input_loop)

root = tk.Tk() #Macht Fenster auf

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=300, bg="#4d4d4d") #Im Fenster, gibt Struktur vor
canvas.grid(columnspan=2, rowspan=4)

dir_file = tk.StringVar() #Darin wird dateipfad gespiechert, var string, global definiert

#logo
logo = Image.open('logo.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo) #konvertiert das in ein Bild das vom tkinter eingelesen werden kann
logo_label = tk.Label(image=logo, bg="#4d4d4d") #erstellt Label das auf Canvas dargestellt werden kann
logo_label.image = logo #einfach machen nicht hinterfragen
logo_label.grid(column=0, row=0) #plazierung des Logos

#current value
current_text = tk.StringVar()
value_text = tk.Text(root, width=8, height=0, bg="#999999")
value_text.insert(1.0, str(current_text) + 'ppm')
current_text.set(str(CO2.meas.live_co2))
value_text.config(font=("Agency FB", 40))
value_text.tag_configure("center", justify="center")
value_text.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end") #Nicht hinterfragen!
value_text.grid(column=1,row=0)

#instructions dir
inst_dir = tk.Label(root, text="Choose your measurement folder:", bg="#4d4d4d")
inst_dir.config(font=("Agency FB", 20))
inst_dir.grid(column=0, row=1)

#instructions Filename
inst = tk.Label(root, text="Choose your measurement Filename:", bg="#4d4d4d")
inst.config(font=("Agency FB", 20))
inst.grid(column=0, row=2)

#browse button
browse_text = tk.StringVar()
browse_btn = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:get_dir(), textvariable=browse_text, bg="#1a8d20", fg="white")
browse_btn.config(font=("Agency FB", 30))
browse_text.set("Browse")
browse_btn.grid(column=1,row=1)

#Filename
entry = tk.Entry(root, bg="#999999")
entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

#Measurement button
mes_btn_txt = tk.StringVar()
mes_btn = tk.Button(root,command=lambda:start_measurement(), textvariable=mes_btn_txt, bg="#1a8d20", fg="white")
mes_btn.config(font=("Agency FB", 20))
mes_btn_txt.set("Start measurement")
mes_btn.grid(columnspan=2, column=0, row=3)

#Measurement list
option_chosen = tk.StringVar()
option_chosen.set(options[0])
opt = tk.OptionMenu(root, option_chosen, *options)
opt.config(font=("Agency FB", 20))
opt.grid(column=0,row=4)

#Measurment limit
limit_entry = tk.Entry(root, bg='#999999')
limit_entry.grid(column=1, row=4)

root.after(200,input_loop)

root.mainloop()
```

Sensor script (named `CO2.py`):

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import threading
import serial
import time
import csv

class meas (threading.Thread):

    log = False
    live_co2 = 0
    path = '/home/desktop'
    flag_first = True
    flag_last = False
    type = "manual"
    t = 0
    num = 0
    res = 1
    a = 1
    b = 0.1


    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print('starting measurement')

        ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=.5)

        print("  AN-137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 Via UART\n")

        ser.flushInput()
        time.sleep(1)

        while True:
            ser.flushInput()
            ser.write(b"\xFE\x44\x00\x08\x02\x9F\x25")
            time.sleep(self.a)
            resp = ser.read(7)
            high = resp[3]
            low = resp[4]
            co2 = (high * 256) + low
            self.live_co2 = co2

            if self.log:
                if self.flag_first:
                    header = ['t', 'ppm']

                    with open(self.path, 'w') as csv_file:
                        csv_w = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=header)
                        csv_w.writeheader()
                    self.flag_first = False
                    self.flag_last = True
                    i = 1

                t_wert = self.a + i * (self.a + self.b)

                with open(self.path, 'a') as csv_file:
                    csv_w = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=header)
                    werte = {'t': t_wert, 'ppm': co2}
                    csv_w.writerow(werte)
                    print(t_wert, co2)

                if self.type == "time" and t_wert >= float(self.t):
                    self.log = False
                    self.t = 0
#                    i = 0
                elif self.type == "number" and float(self.num) == i:
                    self.log = False
                    i = 0
                    self.num = 0

                i += 1

            if self.flag_last and not self.log:
                self.flag_first = True
                self.flag_last = False

            time.sleep(meas.b)
```

Comment: There isn't quite enough code in your question to tell what's going on (for example the variable `current_text` is undefined). One thing I did notice is that it changes `CO2`'s attributes and there does not appear anything to prevent concurrent access to them if it's being do concurrently by both threads. If true, that may be causing problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. current_text is defined by current_text = tk.StringVar(). I took out the rest of the code because it would be to long. I accidentally removed the definition of current_text. However I only read the variable. Can that also cause an issue?

Comment: Yes, just reading a variable can be an issue. When doing concurrent programming, access to shared resources such as global variables (and their attributes) has to be coordinated. A simple way to do that is to using a `threading.Lock` and writing code that always acquires it before access to the variable, and then and releases it afterward. Not doing so could indeed be the problem. Note that you can use a `with` statement to simplify the process.

Comment: @martineau I used `threading.Lock` now, but it didn't change anything. I am still only able to read out 0.

Comment: First change `self.live_co2 = co2` to `meas.live_co2 = co2` inside `meas.run()` function.  Second, `current_text` is not associated to any widget, so updating it inside `input_loop()` function does not change any content of widgets.

Comment: More concretely, to display the current value read by the sensor in your GUI, create a widget that references `current_text` so that any changes to its value will automatically be shown. For example you could refer to it in a `Label` somewhere via `my_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=current_text)`. You could also use a `Button` in a similar manner.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you that worked. If you post your comment as an answer I wall mark it as correct.
I will add the label. Thanks a lot.